# Alternative for SharePoint 2010 Workflow Impersonation Step

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, designer-workflow, list-form, impersonation

In our SharePoint Online site, I have a Form Library with an InfoPath form behind it, as well as a SharePoint 2010 workflow. The only reason I used the SP 2010 workflow platform was for the impersonation step. We need the impersonation step because this form and library is for COVID-19 Screening, so it is a HIPAA violation if people see each others' information in these forms. The current workflow removes the submitter's permissions to the file in the library once they've submitted/added the form to the library. Basically, we need people to have access to the form, but not to the library.

I've tried using this recommendation for Power Automate (https://noellawlor.wordpress.com/2018/01/18/setting-sharepoint-item-list-permissions-with-flow/), but it's not jiving with my Form library. When I use the triggers "When an item is created" or "When a file is created", Power Automate cannot find my Form library. Does PA not recognize Form libraries?

At the end of the day, I'm just looking for a way for users to be able to fill out a form, submit it, but not have access to the library or the files in the library where the form is submitted. Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Did you try setting item level permissions on your library? (library settings -> advance settings)

Comment: @RohitWaghela there's not an option for item level permissions in my libraries. In my lists, yes, but not in my libraries. And even if I could turn that on, I still need a workflow that will automatically change the permissions on the file/form when it is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Based on you description, I understand that you want to use flow on elevated privileges in the SharePoint Online.

Here're some references for you:

[Elevated privileges in power automate.](https://poszytek.eu/en/microsoft-en/office-365-en/powerautomate-en/elevated-permissions-in-microsoft-flow/)

[How to use Flow on elevated privileges in SharePoint Online](https://michalguzowski.pl/how-to-use-flow-on-elevated-privileges-in-sharepoint-online/)